# most idiomatic way to structure a client side REST library?

Tags: java, rest, sdk, access-modifiers, idioms

I'm writing a REST API. I want to separate my classes into neat little folders but I still want them all to have package access to eachother.

The reason for this is that I want one class only to have public access.

Example:

```
+---com.mysuper.sdk
|
+------ models
|          |---- Model.java
+------ controllers
|          |---- Controller.java
|
+---PublicAPI.java
```

1. PublicAPI.java needs to be able to see all the models and controllers.
2. The controllers need to be able to see the models.
3. Anyone who uses my library should only be able to see PublicAPI.java

What is the most idiomatic way to go about this?

Comment: *I am tempted to put all the files in one package and give them all package access except for PublicAPI.java which would be public but that seems sloppy.

Comment: Why do you have only one class that is public? I think this is not really a great way to structure your API. You should have various interfaces that are public (where appropriate) and then implementation classes that are package access. You can use a factory interface to instantiate or service provider interface to instantiate the implementation for a given public interface.

Comment: It was given to me this way.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It was originally written that way and I inherited it.  I think the reason for this might be that they only want the user to have to instantiate one instance of the API object.  Can you you perhaps show me like a simple example of what you mean? I'm having a hard time understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to express what your code, meaning Java convention, would be to have three packages for your code: `com.mysuper.sdk`, `com.mysuper.sdk.models` & `com.mysuper.sdk.controllers`.

That being said, nowhere in the Java Language Specification (September 2015) does it require package names to reflect the underlying folder structure. Take example below:

`./src/com/mysuper/sdk/PublicAPI.java`

```
package com.mysuper.sdk;

// Public class.
public class PublicAPI {
    // Main method.
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[args.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(new Controller().translateNumbers(numbers));
    }
}
```

`./src/com/mysuper/sdk/controllers/Controller.java`

```
package com.mysuper.sdk;

// Package protected class.
class Controller {
    // Private model.
    private Model model = new Model();

    // Package protected method.
    String translateNumbers(int... numbers) {
        String translation = "";
        for (int number : numbers) {
            translation = translation + model.get(number) + " ";
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

`./src/com/mysuper/sdk/models/Model.java`

```
package com.mysuper.sdk;

// Package protected class.
class Model {
    // Private database.
    private String[] database = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    // Package protected method.
    String get(int number) {
        if (number < 0 || number > 9) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Number " + number + " is not between 0 and 9.");
        } else {
            return database[number];
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this code with `javac` will not throw any syntax errors, because the code is syntactically correct. Try it yourself:

```
javac -d bin ./src/com/mysuper/sdk/PublicAPI.java \
./src/com/mysuper/sdk/controllers/Controller.java \
./src/com/mysuper/sdk/models/Model.java

java -cp ./bin com.mysuper.sdk.PublicAPI 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

You should get output along the lines of:

```
zero one two three four five six seven eight nine
```

All of this having been said, there are a couple of reasons why you should stick to organising your classes into separate packages.

1. Most IDEs will treat packages that do not correlate with your folder structure as fatal compilation errors.
2. This is convention as it aids in readability of code, guiding other developers to the folders containing your classes.
3. It will encourage your to better encapsulate your code to separate responsibilities of your code modules.

If you wanted to get a similar result while also following Java best practice, I would encourage you to follow Michael Aaron Safyan's advice and familiarise yourself with [Factory Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to abstract the implementation of your SDK from your public interface.

How best to implement said pattern for your project is better left for another question.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this and it works.  Your answer is very well written, documented, and easy to understand, great work. I agree with you that I should use the Factory Method pattern but I will use this hacky solution in the mean time until I get the time to restructure the SDK better. You have helped me greatly.